# React native invalid event target

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs

I have an application for React (Web) and React Native who share some code. For example i use `axios` for api call and `Observable` from `rxjs`, on the web this is working fine, on the native part (React Native) I get this error:

> invalid event target
>
> setupSubscription ../node_modules/rxjs/observable/FromEventObservable.js:189:32

If i run the application in debug mode, i don't get this error.

Any suggestions?

I use react-native `v0.55`, react `16.x.x`, `rxjs5.4.0`.

I have tried and update the `rxjs` to latest version, but i get the same error.

**The axios call:**

```
export const loginEpic = (action$) =>
  action$
   .ofType(LOGIN_REQUEST)
   .debounceTime(1000)
   .mergeMap((action) =>
     Observable.fromPromise(
       axios.post('auth/login', {
         username: action.payload.username,
         password: action.payload.password,
       })
     )
     .map((response) => response.data)
     .mergeMap((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        if (data) {
          if (data.errors) {
            return [loginFailure(data.errors)]
          } else {
            // Storage.setUserLocalStorage(data)
            return [loginSuccess(data)]
          }
        } else {
           return []
        }
      })
      .catch(() =>
        Observable.of(
          loginFailure({ serverFailureMesssage: 'Login-ul nu a functionat.' })
      )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I have tried to make an example using Expo:

https://snack.expo.io/@aciobanita/rxjs---redux-observable-example